# Dynamically change labels/symbology to create multiple maps of the same dataset in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I'm working in ArcMap 10.1.  I have a data-set of multiple acreage fields that I am joining against a polygon shapefile.  Let's say I have acreage fields X, Y & Z (in reality there about a dozen acreage figures per feature/polygon).  I have a label expression that shows an acreage figure for each polygon on the map.

Now, I'd like to automatically create maps, each showing the same polygons, but with different acreage figures (from X, Y or Z) & different symbology (Quantities -> Graduated colors) for each of my acreage fields.

Initially, I was hoping I could use data-driven pages to handle this, but there doesn't seem to be any way to dynamically switch label expressions (or symbology) based on the current page, for example.

I have some experience using the arcpy scripting lib, so that is an option as well (though I couldn't figure out how to update my symbology based on the current acreage field).

How can I do this without manually making a data-frame (or .mxd file) for each acreage field.  That is, I want to avoid having to manually make several dozen maps showing the exact same features, just with different labels/symbology.

Comment: Data driven pages doesn't change symbology or labels. It changes the location based on a list of input features, while maintaining the look and feel of the map. So it sounds like you want to do the exact opposite. So, yes, you'll need to create 1 layer for each combo of label style and symbol style. This is something you'd need to do anyways. So if you had four different combinations, you'd have 4 different layers that you would toggle on/off depending on which style you wanted to look at. If I've misunderstood your intent, I apologize in advance.

Comment: arcpy mapping may let you alter the label style, but it definitely won't let you alter the symbology without a preexisting layer that you can reference with the symbol style and settings you need.  So you have to manually set up the symbology in its own layer somewhere, either in a map or a layer file.  May as well do it in a map.  Only ArcObjects gives you the control you need to make on the fly symbology in a map just using code.

Comment: Create multiple groups with names matching page names. Insert your layer in each. Make script to shuffle trough pages making one group visible at a time. Export pages as you go